# How to access HttpRequest from urls.py in Django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Basically I want to use a generic view that lists objects based on a username. Now, the question is, how do I do something like:

```
(r'^resources/$',
  ListView.as_view(
    queryset=Resources.objects.filter(user=request.user.username),
    ...
  )
)
```

I couldn't find a way to access the HttpRequest (request) object though... Or do I need to use my own views and do all object selection there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to clutter your URLconf directly, you can do it like so:

```
(r'^resources/$',
 lambda request: ListView.as_view(queryset=Resources.objects.filter(user=request.user.username), ...)(request)
)
```

Or access the request by subclassing the view:

```
class MyListView(ListView):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.queryset = Resources.objects.filter(user = request.user.username)
        return super(MyListView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try subclassing the generic view:

```
class PublisherListView(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Resources.objects.filter(user=self.request.user.username)
```

Then your urls entry would look like:

```
(r'^resources/$',
  PublisherListView.as_view(
    ...
  )
)
```

More information on dynamic filtering in class based views can be found here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#dynamic-filtering

Comment: I agree. This is the correct way to do this. I'm sick of urls.py getting unmanageable.

Comment: Sorry, AndiDog, `request` would come from `self` in class based views. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: If you look at your code again... now where does `self` come from? ;) The `dispatch` method must be overridden because that's the one that gets the request object. It's impossible to put per-request stuff in a class variable like you do.