# How to access HttpRequest from urls.py in Django 1.2

Tags: python, django

I need to do the same thing asked in [How to access HttpRequest from urls.py in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838480/how-to-access-httprequest-from-urls-py-in-django) but using version 1.2. Sorry, is what I have. I don't want to clutter the urls.py, so the two solutions given are not valid for me :)

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I think that the only way to do this is by using a custom view function :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.views.generic.list_detail import object_list

url('^URL_HERE/(?P<object_id>\d+)$', lambda request, *a, **k: object_detail(request, *a,
                       queryset=MyModel.objects.filter(user=request.user),
                       template="myapp/mytmplate.html", **k) )
```

Comment: Ok, this worked fine (with little adjustments, like `object_id` param needed by `object_detail`). Thanks.

Comment: fixed the answer to address the issue. thanks for the accept! :D