# django - access GET variable from urls.py

Tags: django, django-urls, django-haystack, geodjango

I'm implementing django-haystack for the first time and need to make a geo-spatial search.  Is it possible to access user inputs from urls.py?

I followed the haystack documentation and was able to do basic search using

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from haystack.forms import ModelSearchForm, HighlightedSearchForm
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
from haystack.views import SearchView
from haystack.views import SearchView, search_view_factory

**sqs = SearchQuerySet().all()**

urlpatterns = patterns('haystack.views',
url(r'^$', search_view_factory(
    view_class=SearchView,
    template='search/search.html',
    searchqueryset=sqs,
    form_class=HighlightedSearchForm
    ), name='haystack_search'),
)
```

I would need to do **sqs = SearchQuerySet().dwithin('location', user_location, D(mi=5))**

where user_location will be an user input and going to be passed through GET variable, is there any way I can access that here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [How to access HttpRequest from urls.py in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838480/how-to-access-httprequest-from-urls-py-in-django)

Then your code looks like

```
urlpatterns = patterns('haystack.views',
url(r'^$', lambda request, *args, **kwargs: search_view_factory(
    view_class=SearchView,
    template='search/search.html',
    searchqueryset=SearchQuerySet().dwithin('location', request.GET.get('user_location'), D(mi=5)),
    form_class=HighlightedSearchForm
    ), name='haystack_search')(request, *args, **kwargs),
)
```

Normally its better to explicitly write a view to invoke corresponding search view.

Comment: `Normally its better to explicitly write a view to invoke corresponding search view.` - yes, do not turn `urls.py` into psuedo-view controller.