# Django Pass custom variables to template while using default views

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates, django-urls

I am currently using a default django view (PasswordChangeView), but I have my own custom template that I want to use with it. I am achieving this by writing this:

```
path('changepassword/', PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='account/change_password.html', 
                                     success_url = '/changepassword/'), name='password_change'),
```

But in that template there is a variable like so: `{{ var }}`. Is there a way I can pass a value to that variable from urls.py? Or do I need to create an entire new custom view to pass this single variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can pass extra parameters with:

```
path(
    'changepassword/',
    PasswordChangeView.as_view(
        template_name='account/change_password.html', 
        success_url = '/changepassword/'
    ),
    name='password_change',
    kwargs={'var': value_of_var}
),
```

Where you replace *`value_of_var`* with the value `{{ var }}` should use. This works because the URL parameters are also passed to as variables to the template.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't specific enough in my question. This worked for fixed value variables, but is there any way to pass things based on 'request'? (such as request.user.is_anonymous, which normally I can use in a view.)

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838480/how-to-access-httprequest-from-urls-py-in-django but for the newer django version

Comment: @figbar: the `request` object is also passed to the template, you can thus for example write `{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}...{% endif %}` in the template.